# PLY: Illegal Character '+'

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, ply

I am working on a python parser using ply and I have to parse input in the form of:

```
VAR VAR1 001 
+000 000 000 000
```

Where the code would create a variable named VAR 1 then assign the value 0 to it

the regex I wrote for the instanciation is:

```
t_INST = r'[\+|-]0[ ][0-9][0-9][0-9][ ][0-9][0-9][0-9][ ][0-9][0-9][0-9][ ][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

However when running my programme, PLY prints the following:

```
Illegal character '+'
```

---

A reproducer follows:

```
import ply.lex as lex

tokens = ['INST']
t_INST = r'[+-]0[ ](\d{3}[ ]){3}\d{3}';
t_ignore  = ' \t'
def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

lexer = lex.lex()

def parse(input_string):
    ret = []
    lexer.input (input_string)
    while True:
        tok = lexer.token()
        if not tok:
            break      # No more input
        ret.append((tok.type, tok.value))
    return ret

print parse("+0 000 000 000")
```

Comment: You should use \d to denote characters and also use {} to denote repeating sequences:  [\+-](?:\d{3}\s?){4}

Comment: Why the backslash? You'd want that in a normal context, but it doesn't make sense inside a character class. Actually, unless `|` is a valid first character, you probably want `[+-]`, not `[+|-]`, too.

Comment: BTW, it'd be helpful to have your reproducer -- while remaining as *minimal* as possible -- be expanded to the point where it's *complete* and *verifiable*, as given in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Right now, someone needs to do rather a fair bit of work to reproduce the bug.

Comment: an MVCE of my parser https://pastebin.com/sDW3CdyK

Comment: Within the question, please. Or at least somewhere without ads (if you're using adblock, you might not have noticed that pastebin.com is full of 'em); https://gist.github.com/ is a good choice.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: https://gist.github.com/bjornefitte/ab0651e1b490eeaa4a2a4eeb3f32a657

Comment: That doesn't actually fail when it's run (presumably because `parse()` is never called?) To be **complete** and **verifiable**, a MCVE should actually contain enough data to actually trigger the failure. (One of the nice things about gists, of course, is that you can edit them in place -- or check them out with git, edit the code with your local editor, and commit them again).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry, not used to gists ... anyhow. I have fixed it

Comment: So, here's an easy experiment. Change your regex to `t_INST = r'[+-]0[ ]'`; you'll notice that it matches. Thus, the problem isn't anything to do with the `+`.

Comment: Your real data, by the way, doesn't actually match the format given in your comment. `+0 000 000 000` is by no means a match for `(+|-) XXX XXX XXX XXX`.

Comment: `[\+|-]` is valid regex. Where does that error eminate from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
print parse("+0 000 000 000")
```

doesn't match your stated input format of

```
VAR VAR1 001 
+000 000 000 000
```

If the *actual* data is in the same form as `+0 000 000 000`, then you actually want:

```
t_INST = r'[+-]0\s(?:\d{3}\s){2}\d{3}'
```

...with which output is: `[('INST', '+0 000 000 000')]`

Comment: This kinda the regex I gave in my answer using the `\s` for shortcut and non capturing group. This sounds more like a comment for my question. In addition, you used `{2}` and should be `{3}`

Comment: For the OP's test data, no, it really **should** be `{2}`. Their comments are misleading about the actual data format in use. (This is why I spent the time hounding them into providing a real reproducer, instead of writing an answer directly).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to escape `+` within character classes. You can use:

```
t_INST = r'[+|-]0[ ][0-9][0-9][0-9][ ][0-9][0-9][0-9][ ][0-9][0-9][0-9][ ][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
   this-----^
```

Anyway, you can shorten your regex like this:

```
t_INST = r'[+|-]0[ ][0-9]{3}[ ][0-9]{3}[ ][0-9]{3}[ ][0-9]{3}'
```

Or even:

```
t_INST = r'[+|-]0[ ]([0-9]{3}[ ]){3}[0-9]{3}'
```

Also noticed you used `[+|-]`, this is a character class and does not work with alternations, so you have to change it to `[+-]`.

So, a final regex (using `\d` as shortcut for `[0-9]`) would be:

```
t_INST = r'[+-]0[ ](\d{3}[ ]){3}\d{3}'
```

Btw, you sample text says:

```
+000 000 000 000
```

But the regex you are using matches this:

```
+0 000 000 000 000
```

So, if you the data you want to match is `+000 000 000 000`, then you have to change the regex to:

```
t_INST = r'[+-](\d{3}[ ]){3}\d{3}'
```

Comment: ...the issue here (ie. the bad behavior on account of which I chose to write a competing answer rather than comment on this one) is that you wrote an answer without actually having a genuine reproducer that could create their problem, and thus with no assurance that you *really* knew what the OP's problem actually was. Even if `re.compile(r'[\+|-]').match('+')` didn't work, I'd agree that there would be strong grounds for speculation, but that's not the case here: The original code was *bad*, but (testably!) not broken on any of the grounds initially given.

Comment: ...indeed, `re.compile(r'[\+|-]0[ ][0-9][0-9][0-9][ ][0-9][0-9][0-9][ ][0-9][0-9][0-9][ ][0-9][0-9][0-9]').match('+0 000 000 000 000')` returns a match.